# error TS2362: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type

Tags: angular

In my angular 8 application I am getting error error TS2362: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.  in the code below at line

const source: any = timer(0, environment.corePingIntervalSeconds * 1000);

```
const source: any = timer(0, environment.corePingIntervalSeconds * 1000);
    source.subscribe(() => {
       this.checkIfCoreApiIsAvailable()
       .pipe(first())
       .subscribe(resp  => {

       }, err => console.log(err));
     });
```

Comment: What is the value / type of  `environment.corePingIntervalSeconds`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use the Number interface:

```
timer(0, Number(environment.corePingIntervalSeconds) * 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
 +timer(0, environment.corePingIntervalSeconds * 1000)
```

the plus in front converts it to a number type

Answer (score 0):

*emphasized text*Left side value of arithmetic operator must be of type `number, any, bigint, or enum`. In your case value of  `environment.corePingIntervalSeconds` is not belongs to these type. You Should use explicit typecasting in this case.

***Your correct syntax will be like below***

```
const source: any = timer(0, (environment.corePingIntervalSeconds as any) * 1000);
```